# Eclipse view filtered results

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to search for references of the method toString which I've overridden in my class MyClass.

Search results showed any toString method call even though it's not called on the object of MyClass. I figured I need to use "References to Overridden" in the search result view. When i check "References to overridden", title in search result view gets updated to reflect this selection.

```
XXXXXXXXX - 1,051 references in project (17 matches filtered from view)
```

However my problem is that the search results don't get updated, eclipse still shows all the 1051 references. Only the title says 17 matches filtered but the search results still have 1051 references. Is there a way I could only see the filtered results ?

Comment: Those menu options remove things from the results - so 17 results matching 'references to overridden' have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

toString is a java method and it will search in all your referenced java jar's and resulting the results

Answer (score 0):

1. Select `Group by Project` in your `Search View`. After that, it should be clear what's your source code and what's library.

[image]

2. Only select the `Sources` checkbox when using the `Search Dialog`.

[image]